# Firing a TTL on-camera flash and manual off-camera flashes via radio triggers

Tags: nikon, wireless-triggers, ttl, wireless-flash, hotshoe-flash

I want to use an on-camera TTL flash and off-camera manual flashes simultaneously. That is, when I press the shutter button, I want my main on-camera flash to fire using TTL and my off-camera manual flashes to fire at once with my main flash via a radio trigger.

Using the off-camera flashes in the optical slave mode is not an option because sometimes they might not be able to see my main flash.

I have (or will soon get) a Nikon D750, a Nikon SB-910 as my on-camera iTTL flash, four manual Yongnuo YN560 IV as my off-camera flashes, and a Yongnuo YN560-TX radio trigger to fire them. I also have four PocketWizard Plus III radio triggers that can be used instead of the YN560-TX, but I’d prefer the Yongnuo trigger.

What setup would you recommend? Perhaps there is a hotshoe splitter that would pass the iTTL signal unchanged to my on-camera SB-910 and also pass the main fire signal to the YN560-TX? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the YN-560TX has no hotshoe; and the pass-through shoes on the RF-603/RF-603II, and RF-605 are *not* full TTL passthrough.  The YN-622N *does* have full TTL passthrough, but won't trigger the YN-560IVs directly. So if you're sticking with the built-in radio receivers in the YN-560IVs, you have to stack triggers.

If you want to go this route, get a pair of YN-622Ns (or any other radio triggers with a full TTL passthrough hotshoe), stack your YN-560TX (or an RF-603II or RF-605) on a YN-622N acting as a receiver, and sandwich the other YN-622 to act as a transmitter/master between the SB-910 and the camera hotshoe.  And then test how the delay caused by the stacking affects your sync speed.

Comment: Thank you! That could work for me. Do you know if it is be possible to replace the two YN-622N with a TTL cord in this setup? Are there any TTL cords with two hotshoes, one at the end of the cable and another right above the camera hotshoe, the latter having full TTL passthrough?

Comment: That would probably be better than the 622s, since the 622s may actually manipulate signal, while a cable would be passive pass-through. And all TTL cables have hotshoe/foot connections on both ends. The main issue is how long a cable do you need? Most are designed for flash brackets and aren't particularly long. Flashzebra.com sells long ones, or you could [DIY a longer one with CAT5](http://www.diyphotography.net/the-strobist-corner-extending-your-ttl-flash-cord/) or use a [Pixel Componor](http://www.lightingrumours.com/pixel-componor-ttl-cords-done-properly-1453).

Comment: A regular TTL cord that has one male hotshoe connector on the camera end and one female hotshoe on the flash end won't do. I need a cable with one more female hotshoe above the camera hotshoe. That hotshoe must have full TTL passthrough. Then I would attach my on-camera flash to that hotshoe and the YN-560TX to the other end of the TTL cord. Thus the cord can be really short, the length doesn't matter. There are TTL cords that have two female hotshoes, but I have no idea whether they would work. http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1005408-REG/energizer_ene_ttlu_multi_fit_ttl_flash_cord.html

Comment: I'm also looking into using two Nikon AS-10 TTL adapters linked with a Nikon SC-26 TTL cord, but I don't know if that could work either.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1032196-REG/vello_speedy_camera_rotating_flash.html) bracket comes with a cable that looks like it's got a pass-through for the hotshoe. Looks like you could mount your on-camera on this, put the pass-though cable directly on the camera, then the Yongnuo transmitter on top of that.

Comment: I don't think that particular cable has a pass-through hotshoe directly on top of the camera hotshoe. See the fourth product picture here: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/750438-REG/Vello_OCS_N1_5_TTL_Off_Camera_Flash_Cord.html.

Comment: But I get your idea. Find a TTL cable that has two hotshoes (one on each end) and use a flash bracket. Thanks. That's a little too cumbersome, but it could work.