# How can I use an on-camera TTL flash with a Yongnuo 605N to trigger my off-camera manual speedlights?

Tags: off-camera-flash, ttl, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, hotshoe

I am using a Nikon D7000. I want to use an SB700 on camera in TTL as well as have my Yongnuo RF-605N trigger my off-camera speedlights in manual. The RF-605N does NOT perform TTL pass-through. I see that there are some hotshoe cords with a hotshoe on both ends, but have heard reviews that claim that they do not fire both hotshoes simultaneously. I don't understand what sense that would make?? I am not opposed to using a flash bracket or having the trigger connected via cable if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firing a TTL on-camera flash and manual off-camera flashes via radio triggers](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61040/firing-a-ttl-on-camera-flash-and-manual-off-camera-flashes-via-radio-triggers). My answer there was get a set of YN-622Ns, and stack triggers.

Answer (score 1):

The SB700s have built-in wireless triggers for multiple flash-unit photography. I am assuming all your flashes are SB700/800/900 or compatible. You will not need the Yongnuo RF.

The master flash unit on your camera commands the remote units. The flash mode can be set on each flash unit.

http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/245/SB-700.html

If you have additional flashes that are not Nikon, you could use optical triggering for them.

Comment: I am using Yongnuo 560IV & 510EX flashes. I am not using the CLS system or optical slave because I may need to fire flashes that are concealed behind barriers. I am also using the RF605N because it very easy to control each flash on/off simpler (one button) than through the Nikon menu.

Comment: I was wondering if that might be the situation. You may want an iTTL pass-through hotshoe with a pc connection for the RF. The reliability issue with multiple flashes is due to voltage needed to fire multiple flashes. With an RF trigger, this may not be a problem.

Comment: Btw, I've gotten a slave on a cheap dice-sized cube optical trigger to work behind obsticles (backlight a decorative window) simply by using a well-placed mirror.  A sensor cube on a cord should work too.

Comment: Would this cord work for what I am looking for? http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1005408-REG/energizer_ene_ttlu_multi_fit_ttl_flash_cord.html  The switch on it looks as if you can only use one hotshoe at a time though.  I would mount the flash on one of the hotshoes, and the 605N on the other. I want this setup so that I can control the off camera lights on/off. Optical trigger does not help because I may need to turn off some flashes from the camera.